# Facebook Page Tab/Facebook Canvas App/Fan Page

Tags: facebook

This all sounds confusing;

I have a Facebook Canvas App with the same name as the Fan Page. I would like to add an iFrame tab to the Fan Page to promote and link to the Canvas App. My question is do I have to create a new app for the iFrame tab, or do I open my app settings for the canvas app and add settings for a page tab as well in there. Facebook don;t seem to have much documentation and they are changing things for app profiles soon, so I want to make sure I keep my fans of the page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Basically it goes like this.

You have an iFrame app.

The iFrame app has a canvas which is where you load your html for your app from your webserver with whatever language you want (.NET, PHP etc)

Then you can add this iFrame app to your page.

When you go to http://apps.facebook.com/yourappname

You will be shown the app by itself. When you add it to your page and load it via the tab on the menu of your page it will show you the app within the space on your page (an iframe).

You can use code to detect whether you are on a page or not to display different things.

Comment: adding your own app to a fanpage can be tricky try this (src: hyperartts): `www.facebook.com/dialog /pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&next=YOUR_URL`